# Storing information in the access database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Hi I'm trying to store the information of a new element in the datagrid, In the app is open the information is there, but when we close it and open it again, all the new information dissapear, can someone help?

```vb
Dim cmdSql As String

'If txtNumero.Text = "1" Then
cmdSql = "INSERT INTO Fatura (Cliente, Data, ValorTotal) " &
        "VALUES ('" & txtCliente.Text & "', #" &
        dataFatura.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & "#, " &
        Replace(txtValorTotal.Text.ToString, ",", ".") & ")"

GerirLigacao.ExecutarCmdSQL(cmdSql)



cmdSql = "SELECT TOP 1 Numero FROM Fatura ORDER BY Numero DESC"
Dim r As DataSet = GerirLigacao.obterDados(cmdSql)
    txtNumero.Text = r.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Numero")
    txtNrFatura.Text = txtNumero.Text
    Dim msg = "Fatura guardada com sucesso"
    Dim titulo = "Guardar"
    Dim botoes = MessageBoxButtons.OK
    Dim icone = MessageBoxIcon.Information
    MessageBox.Show(msg, titulo, botoes, icone)
```

> Gerirligacao

```vb
Public Shared Sub ExecutarCmdSQL(ByVal comando As String)
    Try
        Dim cmdSql As New OleDbCommand(comando, ligacao)
        cmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim msg = "Aconteceu um erro de execução." & vbNewLine
        Dim botoes = MessageBoxButtons.OK
        Dim icone = MessageBoxIcon.Error
        MessageBox.Show(msg & ex.Message, "ERRO", botoes, icone)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing to do - the thing that you already should have done - is test the value returned by `ExecuteNonQuery`. If that is not zero then the data is being saved and the issue is how you are looking for it. That's not uncommon with Access but we need to establish exactly what problem we're trying to solve first.

Comment: I agree - some basic troubleshooting is required here. Open your MS Access file and see if the data is in there.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the database file in the Solution Explorer, click on it and in the Properties grid set `Copy To Output Directory` to `Copy If Newer`

[image]

More info: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx

Now might also be a good time to tell you that you could make some serious improvements to your database access code; this way you're doing it makes things very hard work and the code is highly insecure (take a read of http://bobby-table.com for more info). Microsoft used to have a great set of walkthroughs at http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxsa23t6(vs.80).aspx - that documentation has now been archived (being at least 15 years old) and I cant download them on a cellphone to check it "creating a simple data application" is still prt of it. There are a good number of tutorials on YouTube about how to use tableadapters and datasets if that's the route you want to use, though the modern technology (and widest spread of knowledge) these days is probably available for Entity Framework. Google for "getting started with entity framework" and take a look; I'd highly recommend you go this way than your existing route of using weakly typed datasets and direct sql queries

Comment: Hi Caius, thanks for the help, now the application is saving properly the products into the database! Thanks for helping!